# How to integrate sqlite extensions in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, xampp

There's an extension on the http://www.sqlite.org/contrib?orderby=date, extension-functions.c, which integrates the SQRT command in sqlite.

How can I integrate this and use it in my Windows-XAMPP Environment?

For the SQL-Queries i use the Firefox-Extension SQLiteManager and PHP-scripts.

I have created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1a82/21) with an example of my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the extension you would need to compile it in yourself, or Google for a precompiled DLL which is compatible with XAMPP and has the extensions you're using, and then put that in your PHP modules folder on XAMPP.